# Crear un menu con selector (Radio button) en SwiftUI

Tags: menu, swiftui

Quiero implementar un menu para poder ordenar una lista, la siguiente imágen me parece que es lo nativo, como se puede hacer, la carga de menu ya lo tengo, pero no ser como definir los elemetos selecionables.

Para detectar el cambio de valor, creo con un @pubhisherValue me bastaría

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El final lo he conseguido, usando `Picker()` y estilo `.inline`

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum SortListCriteria: String, CaseIterable {
    case idIATA = "IATA Code"
    case airportName = "Airport Name"
    case city = "City"
    case country = "Country"
}

enum SortListDirection: String, CaseIterable {
    case alphabetically = "Alphabetically"
    case reverseAlphabetically = "Reverse Alphabetically"
}

struct FilterMenuView: View {
    var selectedSortCriteria: Binding<SortListCriteria>
    var selectedSortDirection: Binding<SortListDirection>

    var body: some View {
        Menu {
            Section {
                Picker(selection: selectedSortCriteria, label: Text("Sort Criteria")) {
                    ForEach(SortListCriteria.allCases, id: \.self) { option in
                        Text(option.rawValue).tag(option)

                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.inline)
            }
            
            Section {
                Picker(selection: selectedSortDirection, label: Text("Sort Direction")) {
                    ForEach(SortListDirection.allCases, id: \.self) { option in
                        Text(option.rawValue).tag(option)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.inline)
            }
        } label: {
            Label("Filter", systemImage: "line.horizontal.3.decrease.circle")
        }
    }
}

struct FilterMenuView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FilterMenuView(
            selectedSortCriteria: .constant(.idIATA),
            selectedSortDirection: .constant(.alphabetically)
        )
    }
}
```

y en el ViewModel

```swift
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dataListState = DataListState<[CompactModelUI]>.idle
    @Published var dataState = DataState<DetailModelUI>.idle
    
    private var allData: [CompactModelUI] = []
    
    @Published var searchTerm = ""
    private var searchTermCancellable: AnyCancellable?

    //Interceptor change sort criteria
    @Published var selectedFilterOption: SortListCriteria = .idIATA {
        didSet {
            if !allData.isEmpty {
                allData = sortDataList(allData)
                dataListState = .success(allData)
            }
        }
    }

    //Interceptor change sort direction
    @Published var selectedSortDirection: SortListDirection = .alphabetically {
        didSet {
            if !allData.isEmpty {
                switch selectedSortDirection {
                case .alphabetically:
                    allData = sortDataList(allData)
                case .reverseAlphabetically:
                    allData.reverse()
                }
                dataListState = .success(allData)
            }
        }
    }
```

Demostración visual: https://youtube.com/shorts/uoUvww4g1lQ